# Django - allauth - Prevent an unauthenticated user to view pages meant for authenticated users

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am trying to use Django with allauth trying to create a login page.

I am able to login and redirect the user to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL (= "/users/{id}/mypage") page successfully. I have a separate view for /users/{id}/mypage called the UserHomePageView as defined in views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class UserHomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "user_homepage.html"
```

I want a security measure to prevent anyone (basically non-loggedin-users) to navigating to "/users/{id}/mypage" (e.g /users/5/mypage). e.i If unauthenticated user tries to navigate to /users/5/mypage, he/she should get redirected to signin page/homepage.

Basically, how do i present a unauthenticated user to view pages that are meant for authenticated users (I don't want to use template tags users.authenitcated, but wish to override the TemplateView)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another solution which is generally used is to decorate the `dispatch` method with the `login_required` decorator:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class UserHomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "user_homepage.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserHomePageView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

This has the advantage that it works with all methods (get, post, put, etc.), and that using the `login_required` decorator is more DRY than explicitly checking `request.user.is_authenticated` and redirecting.

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful, but how can I override login_required in order to redirect to a specific page when I am not logged-in? I am not exactly sure how login_required decorator works.

Comment: `login_required` takes two optional arguments: `redirect_field_name` and `login_url`. If you are not logged in, you will be redirected to `login_url`. The current page's url will be passed to the `login_url` as a GET parameter under the name in `redirect_field_name` (`'next'` by default). To redirect to a custom url, simply do `@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/my/custom/url/'))`, or specify `LOGIN_URL` in your settings to globally set the default login url.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

By overriding get() and using self.request.user.is_authenticated()

```
class UserHomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "user_homepage.html"
    redirect_field_name = "next"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Overriding TemplateView.get() in order to
        prevent unauthorized user to view UserHomePageView
        '''
        # Redirect to Homepage if user is not signed in
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(self.get_redirect_url())
        # Process normally if User is signed in
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```